# how to make a formula which will give the result as i mentioned in my message

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
A          B          C       D

sam        22         sam        FORMULA
kevin      15         
harry      89         
ben        45
gary       35
```

I have the above employee list (employee name, employee ID). I need to create a formula in column D which shall give me the below result:

In column C, whichever cell I put `sam`, the adjacent cell (in column D) should give me the result as 22 (the item `sam` may repeat numerous times in the column, but still it should give the result)

Comment: Would you mind formatting your question more nicely? It is very difficult to read/understand.

Comment: I assume you want this to work for the other employee names as well?

Answer (score 3):

A simple `VLOOKUP` should solve your problem. This is the formula for cell D1: `=VLOOKUP(C1,A1:B5,2,FALSE)`. Adjust the first argument of this formula for the other cells in column D.

If you want to avoid the `#N/A` output for empty cells in column C use
`=IF(ISBLANK(C1),"",VLOOKUP(C1,A1:B5,2,FALSE))`.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a `VLOOKUP` function.

In D1, type this in:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C5,$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE), 0)`

I'll break this down:

- `=IFERROR` This is so if the cell in column C is empty, you don't get an error
- `C2` This is the 'lookup_value' - what you are looking for
- `$A$2:$B$4` This is the 'table_array' - the range of the data you are searching through. The `$` make this absolute, so you can fill the formula down to other cells
- `2` This is the 'col_index_num' - the column in the range you set (ie. with a range of 2 columns, `2` is the last - or second - column)
- `FALSE` This is the 'range_lookup' - 'FALSE' means look for an exact match.
- `0` This is the output of the formula if the cell in column C is empty. You could also use `""` for a blank string

You can edit this as required

This is an example with other employees as well (C4 is empty, so you get the value `0` in D4):

[image]